# Sign Up button not saving registration info

Tags: java, sql-server, mssql-jdbc

I've made a simple sign up form with Java (Netbeans IDE 8.0.2) and MSSQL (Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio).

Here's the code:

```
public class SignUpForm extends javax.swing.JFrame {

RoliRepository rr = new RoliRepository();
RoliComboBoxModel rcmb = new RoliComboBoxModel();

/**
 * Creates new form SignUpForm
 */
public SignUpForm() {
    initComponents();
    loadComboBox();
    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    this.setLocation(dim.width / 2 - this.getSize().width / 2, dim.height / 2 - this.getSize().height / 2);
}

public void loadComboBox() {
    try {
        List<Roli> lista = rr.findAll();
        rcmb.add(lista);
        roliCMB.setModel((ComboBoxModel) rcmb);
        roliCMB.repaint();
    } catch (CrudFormException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
    }
}

private void signUpBtnActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          
    // TODO add your handling code here:
    try {
        PerdoruesiRepository pr = new PerdoruesiRepository();
        Perdoruesi p = pr.signUpByUsernameAndPassword(fnField.getText(), lnField.getText(), usernameField.getText(), new String(passwordField.getPassword()), new String(confirmPasswordField.getPassword()), roliCMB.getSelectedItem().toString());
        if (p != null && confirmPasswordField.equals(passwordField)) {
                //if(p.getRoliID().getId() == 1){
            //    new AdminMainForm
            //}else{
            //    new UserMainForm
            //}
                new MainForm(p.getRoliID().getId()).setVisible(true);
            this.setVisible(false);
        }
    } catch (CrudFormException ex) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Gabim!");
        //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, ex.getMessage());
    }

}

public static void main(String args[]) {
    /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
    //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
    /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
     * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
     */
    try {
        for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                break;
            }
        }
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SignUpForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SignUpForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SignUpForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(SignUpForm.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    //</editor-fold>

    /* Create and display the form */
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new SignUpForm().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

And Repository:

```
public Perdoruesi signUpByUsernameAndPassword(String fn, String ln, String u, String p, String r, String rl) throws CrudFormException {
    try {
        Query query = em.createQuery("SELECT p FROM Perdoruesi p WHERE p.firstName = :fn AND p.lastName = :ln AND p.username = :us AND p.password=:psw AND p.roliID = :rl");
        query.setParameter("fn", fn);
        query.setParameter("ln", ln);
        query.setParameter("us", u);
        query.setParameter("psw", p);
        query.setParameter("rl", rl);
        return (Perdoruesi) query.getSingleResult();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new CrudFormException("Msg! \n" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

So the problem is that when I input infos like first name, last name... it just shows me this:

```
JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "Gabim!");
```

and at the output it doesnt show any error with database or code.

[image]

Comment: What do you expect `SELECT p FROM Perdoruesi p ...` to return? You haven't specified any column names.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning first of all, thank you for your reply! Can you elaborate more about it please? Thanks sir.

Comment: Open up SSMS or your favourite query tool and execute the query `SELECT p FROM Perdoruesi p`. You'll get an error message: `Msg 207 Level 16 State 1 Line 1 Invalid column name 'p'.` You need to provide a list of column names to be returned from the select statement.